# Streaming audio data from a huggingface dataset, or emulate streaming given the sample data

Tags: streaming, audio-streaming, huggingface-datasets, torchaudio

I would like to access various datasets from huggingface.co that contain audio data. To begin, I am using the GigaSpeech dataset.

I understand how to use an `IterableDataset` (by including `streaming=True` when calling `load_dataset(...)`. However, this appears to download the entire audio file at once, as the returned item has an key `audio` whose value has keys `path` and `array`, where `array` appears to contain the sample data for the entire audio file.

I am using `torchaudio.io.StreamReader`, which appears to support streaming from a URL (i.e. from a remote file). **I am wondering if it might be possible to have the `IterableDataset` (or something like it) iterate over the URLs to the audio files rather than downloading them directly.**

If this is not possible:  I've looked in the cache folder several times and I can't find the audio file or even the folder that `path` seems to allude to. At any rate, since `array` seems to contain the audio data from the file, reading the source file itself appears unnecessary. However, `torchaudio.io.StreamReader` does not seem to support "streaming" from an array. **I would like to know what the best method is to easily perform "streaming" with possible resampling over the `array`** (whose `dtype` is `torch.float64`, but will need to be converted to `numpy.float32` at some point).

Obviously, I could implement my own windowing and resampling on the array, but **it would be much better if I could use something pre-existing that works out of the box very similarly to the StreamReader.**